# Solving ODE containing matrices

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

We have   an ODE $ \psi'(t)_{_{3 \times 3}}=\psi(t)_{3 \times 3}(A_{3 \times 3}+B_{3 \times 3}t)\tag 1$

**Given Data in Question**

1. We have no quarentee that $\psi'(t),\psi(t)$ both have inverse
2. A,B are skew symmetric constant  matrices with determinant $0$
3. We know what is $\psi(0),\psi'(0)$

**Question**

1. How do we solve this ODE and find out what is $\psi(t)$? Means looking for a closed form.

Answer (score 1):

This is matrix equation that can be written as three identical vector equation:
$z'(t)_{1\times3} = z(t)_{1\times3}(A_{3\times3}+B_{3\times3}t)$
Where z is one of the rows of $\psi(t)_{3\times3}$

The solution is of the form:
$z=\vec{v}_1e^t+\vec{v}_2e^{t^2}$
Substitute in original equation:
$v_1e^t+2tv_2e^{t^2}=(v_1e^t+v_2e^{t^2})(A+Bt)$

$e^t: v_1=v_1A$
$te^t: 0=v_1B$
$e^{t^2}: 0=v_2A$
$te^{t^2}: 2v_2=v_2B$

$v_1\in Null(B)\bigcap Null(A-I)$
$v_2\in Null(A)\bigcap Null(B-2I)$

And now the initial condition can be used to find specific $v_1,v_2$

Repeat this proccess three times to obtain $\psi(t)$

Comment: Why would you take $z=\vec{v}_1e^t+\vec{v}_2e^{t^2}$ as initial solution form? Any reason?

Comment: $v_1\in Null(B)\bigcap Null(A-I)$<br/>
$v_2\in Null(A)\bigcap Null(B-2I)$  Please clarify these notations and logic

Comment: This is just the general form for first order equation of this type... $Null(A)$ is a symbol for null space of $A$, this is a group of all vectors which fulfill $Av=0$

Comment: This is wrong. Your method only finds the solution in that special form, but not in general. One can easily find $A$ and $B$ such that intersection of the null spaces is empty. There are solutions for those matrices that your method would not find.

Answer (score 1):

## ATTEMPT #1

1. Take transpose on both sides,then you get

   $ (\psi^T(t)_{_{3 \times 3}})^{'}=-(A_{3 \times 3}+B_{3 \times 3}t) \psi(t)_{3 \times 3}^{T}\tag 1$ We know $-(A_{3 \times 3}+B_{3 \times 3}t) $ is a skew symmetric matrix of order $3\times 3$
2. Now we use a theorem given as follows [image]If we have a angular velocity vector $w(t)$,then we can make a rotation matrix of $3\times 3 $ out of it as follows $R(t)=cos(|w(t)|)I+ sin(|w(t)|)  [\frac{w(t)}{|w(t)|}]_{\times}+ (1-Cos(|w(t)|)) \left(\frac{w(t)}{|w(t)|}\otimes\frac{w(t)}{|w(t)|}\right)$.
3. And we know that derivative of any rotation matrix makes the relationship with angular velocity as follows $R'(t)=[w(t)]_{\times}R(t) \tag 3$ this analogues to equation (1). Now substitute  $[w(t)]_{\times}=-(A_{3 \times 3}+B_{3 \times 3}t)$ and extract $w(t)$ from $-(A_{3 \times 3}+B_{3 \times 3}t)$  ,get R(t). Then $R(t)^T=\psi(t)$.  Hope it has solved the issue.. Please comment

Comment: This will work only if $\psi(t)$ is a rotation matrix... Is this always true?

Comment: So you are saying I have to prove $\psi(t),  \psi'(t)$ as rotation matrix first?

Comment: Let us think this logical connection (if there is skew symmetric matrix)$\Rightarrow$ (There must be a rotation matrix for it) $\Rightarrow$(if there is a rotation matrix then it must satisfy $R'(t)=[w(t)]_{\times}R(t)$) . So can we conclude that $\psi(t)$ as rotation matrix also a solution and there could be other solution too